# *ngIf condition is not updated after an HTTP request is finished?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a button which when clicked by users calls the GitLab API and renders fetched data. Unfortunately I need to click the button twice to show the data. At the very first click it does not display anything.

Here is the HTML template code:

```
<div *ngIf="!afterLogIn">
  <button (click)="apiData()">Gitlab project</button>
</div>

<div class="content" *ngIf="afterLogIn" >

  <div *ngFor="let data of api">
    <div class="item">
      <div class="flag"></div>
      <div class="description">
        <div class="title styles-pro-medium-bold">
          {{ data.name }}
        </div>
        <div class="about styles-pro-small">
          {{ data.description}}
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="more styles-pro-header">
        <div class="more">
          ...
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

my component.ts file:

```
constructor(
    private router: Router,
    private store$: Store<RootStoreState.State>,
    private gitLabApi: GitLabApiService
  ) {}   
apiData() {
        this.gitLabApi.getApi().subscribe(apiData => {
          this.api = apiData;
          console.log(this.api);  // first click showed the data in console

        this.afterLogIn = true;
        });
       }
```

Here is the service I am using:

```
export class GitLabApiService {
    url ='https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects?access_token=sometoken&owned=true&simple=true';
      constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

      getApi(): Observable<any> {
        return this.http.get<any>(this.url);
      }
}
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: wrap your this.api=apiData inside setTimeout function and check

Comment: @Chellappan why setTimeout ?

Comment: if i do the setTime then what is the purpose of using Rxjs? @Chellappan

Comment: can you show the `this.gitLabApi.getApi()` method? My guess is that the API is running outside of the ngZone

Comment: I am guessing API data comes in later time that is why the change detection is not happening

Comment: actually i am using a service. Here gitLabApi is a instance of GitLabApi service. @ PierreDuc

Comment: @Kazi I understand, can you show that code?

Comment: please have a look on the question. I have updated the question. @PierreDuc

Comment: ahh, I'm guessing your component is set to `ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush`

Comment: Just want to check , could you add for the second `*ngIf` this, ```<div class="content" *ngIf="afterLogIn && api" >``` ?

Comment: i dont konw much about ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush. could you please elaborate the solution a bit. thanks. @PierreDuc

Comment: Can you update the question with your component's decorator code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is that change detection is not being triggered. If you want to keep using `OnPush` you need to adjust your code a bit:

```
constructor(
  private router: Router,
  private store$: Store<RootStoreState.State>,
  private gitLabApi: GitLabApiService,
  private cd: ChangeDetectorRef  // add this line
) {} 

apiData() {
  this.gitLabApi.getApi().subscribe(apiData => {
     this.api = apiData;
     this.afterLogIn = true;
     this.cd.markForCheck() // add this line
  });
}
```

Or, you can even use the `async` pipe like this:

```
<div class="content" *ngIf="afterLogIn">
  <div *ngFor="let data of api | async">
  //...
```

and change your code to:

```
apiData() {
  this.api = this.gitLabApi.getApi().pipe(
    tap(() => this.afterLogIn = true)
  );
}
```

Comment: thank you so much. the first method is working properly, even though it's calling the api twice. But 2nd method is bit tricky. as i cant access the`afterLogIn` in my `GitLabApi.service.ts`.  @PierreDuc

Comment: @Kazi but the method `apiData` is inside your component, that's where you add the pipe. That it's calling twice must come from somewhere else in your app. But without seeing your app, it's impossible to tell where

Comment: you are right. is was a mistake. i was calling the api also from my constructor. your code is absolutely right. Off-topic: I am so glad. I am astonished with your knowledge. can you please suggest some books or source where i can learn and be like you someday :)  @PierreDuc

Comment: @Kazi that's nice to hear! Most of it is just practice and working with it every day, but the best resources I can think of are the [docs](https://angular.io/docs) from angular, just read them all (this way you have the latest info), and the [angular-in-depth](https://blog.angularindepth.com/) blogs